# how to validate email address with existing contact or lead in Web2Lead form of Salesforce?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am creating a web2Lead form in salesforce and I need to validate my email address..If any contact or lead with same email address exists in the system I need to pull the information of that contact/lead and show them on my web2lead form..
Any help is greatly admired.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript we can validate email by following RegEx

```
function validateEmail(email){
  var reg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/
  if (reg.test(email)) {
    return true; 
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Reference from [here](http://dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/javascript/UNDS040712-JavaScript-Email-Address-validation-using-Regular-Expression.html)

Comment: @Naveen..thnx but I have already done email address REGULAR EXPRESSION validation, now I need to check if any contact or lead already exists with same email address it AUTOFILL's the remaining fields of web2lead form ..

Comment: Entered data is existing or not by using AJAX concept we have to use.